# Grant Access to a Shared Mailbox From an Application

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, office365, azure-functions, power-automate

[Within Office 365 its apparently not possible to assign a security group to a shared mailbox](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6557837e-d816-4fc6-83a4-24f68348dd60/office-365-admin-center-add-security-group-to-shared-mailbox?forum=Exch2016Adm). This means that all users need to manually be added to the shared mailbox, which is a pain.

[However, Microsoft Graph appears to offer a way to subscribe to changes to a given group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0). As a result my thought was to build a simple azure function application that receives a web-hook from Microsoft Graph when someone is added / deleted from a specific group, and promptly adds / removes the user from the list of shared mailboxes.

The problem I'm having is that Microsoft Graph does not appear to have an API call for granting a user access to a shared mailbox; and I haven't been able to find another Microsoft API that will allow it.

[The only way I've discovered that can even do this programmaticly is with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/add-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps), which requires that I create a user to authenticate rather than granting application access. PowerShell also only has experimental support for Azure Functions right now, and I'm not even sure if Azure Functions supports Exchange Online PowerShell calls or how to install it if needed.

Does anyone know a way to do this with REST calls or JavaScript specifically, or better yet to do it with Microsoft Flow without writing code?

If I don't get any answers on the preferred method soon, I will except a solution on how to do this with an Azure Function or Microsoft Flow and PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an Azure function, you could use Azure automation to create an Azure Runbook that will execute your PowerShell code.

The Runbooks allows you to import modules giving you all the functionality you need to do the Exchange Online PowerShell. It also allows you to store credentials of an Account with the correct level of permissions. (While testing you can use an Exchange Service admin account or a Global admin).

So you could create an Azure AD user, use [Exchange RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/permissions/permissions?view=exchserver-2019) rights to scope it down to only have permissions to what it needs to do for security reasons, then store the creds of that user in the Runbooks credential functionality.

The Runbook can then be [executed from a webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks).

A small note, you cannot add a security group, but you can add a mail enabled security group and give it rights. The group can be hidden from the global address list in Exchange and just use some bogus mail address on the .onmicrosoft.com domain of the tenant.

Only thing to note, this method of using groups for permissions does give the user the correct access rights, but, the mailbox will not automatically be added to Outlook.
The reason for this is that Exchange adds an Automapping flag to the object you give access rights on the mailbox. But setting this flag on a group does not recurse and also add the flags on users, so users would need to manually go into Outlook and tell it to open the mailbox.

**How to manually test in Office 365**
*Confirmed to work 03/12/2018*

1. Adding a new mail enabled security group in Office 365.
2. Creating a new shared mailbox in Office 365.
3. Adding a user to the mail enabled security group.
4. Open the OWA logged in with the user you added to the mail enabled security group
5. Select "**Open another Mailbox**" and selected my shared mailbox.

This is the easiest way to test if the permissions have carried over. But do mind that in Outlook for desktop, the user manually will need to add the mailbox in the settings page, since the auotmapping flag does not carry over.

Also take note of Exchange Online replication time. At its worst it may take up to 30 minutes for everything to propagate properly, but it usually works within 5 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried the mail enabled security group with O365? I tried that yesterday and did not have any success even with manually adding the mailbox. I am wondering if I somehow messed something up, or if your feedback isn’t for O365.

Comment: I added explanation for manual test of the group thing in my post as it gets to messy to read in a comment.

Comment: Thank-you. Since you said it worked, I went back and redid a test case but this time utilizing PowerShell to create the security group rather than the O365 portal. This definitely worked. I'm going to play around with this a little bit and see if I can figure out if I made an error, or if there is something truly different about using PowerShell instead of the GUI. In either case, you answered my question here and helped me out a bunch! Thank-you!

Comment: I used the GUI in the portal to create the group. I have however experienced on loads of my customers Tenants that the GUI can be super inconsistent and have weird behaviours when you do operations in the general AD management area instead of going in the say, the Exchange Control Panel. So it might be a case of the good old "GUI'itis"